# How can one function call another function in the same class? How to fix Unresolved reference error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a class that includes two functions where one of them calls the other one, for example:

```py
class Parser:

    def foo(a):
        return a
 
    def bar(b):
        return foo(b * 2)
```

This errors out with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in bar
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Comment: Either you use `self.foo1(a)` or you mixed the vars and you want to return `foo2(a)`. You should read about Classes

Comment: both not works.

Comment: Please show the code where you are calling `foo2()`.

Comment: The error thrown already in class, not in using the class from outside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You either forgot to have `self` as one of the parameters, or forgot to set the methods to be static with `@staticmethod`.

If you'd like the methods to be instance methods use `self`:

```
class Parser:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo(self, a):
           return a

    def bar(self, a):
           return self.bar(a)
```

You will then have to create an instance of the parser and call bar on this instance, for example:

```
parser = Parser()
print(parser.bar('test'))
```

If you'd like the methods to be static, you'll need to change your class to the following for the static method:

```
class Parser:
    @staticmethod
    def foo(a):
        return a

    @staticmethod
    def bar(a):
        return Parser.foo(a)
```

This will allow you to call the functions without an instance.

```
print(Parser.bar('test'))
```

Comment: +1 for listing both the "static" and "instance" way, although I'm pretty sure the latter is what OP wanted. To top that off one could make the `staticmethod` foo2 a `classmethod`, which avoids the explicit reference to `Parser`.